# Swift iOS Background Color View animation as Timer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to have the background on my viewController start out blue. As one minute passes I want the blue to slowly go down on the screen in 60 seconds. It has finished but the screen is not white.

Here is what I have tried. 
I have created a blue view and divided the screens height by 120. Using a scheduled timer every 1/2 second I lower the screen 1/120th of the way.

It works but it does not look very good. How can I animate this in a way that it would look very smooth.

Comment: Add your code in quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to use timer for that ? Just use the animate block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 60, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    // If you are not using autolayout, just animate the frame. 
    topAnchorConstraint.constant = -view.frame.height // Or any horizontal anchor
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Since this animation is over 60 seconds, I'm assuming you need user interaction during animation which you can set it in the `options` parameter.

**P.S:** You would need another view below this one with a white color to actually reveal a white view below it.